# centos/mysqlでの正規表現についてご教示ください。

Tags: mysql, centos, 正規表現

以下のようなファイルが数千ファイルあります。

000000000001_0_0_**1**_ドキュメント_1111111_001_001.docx

太字の箇所が1であるファイルを一括でmvしたいのですが、どのように記述したら良いでしょうか。

このように記述しましたが上手く抽出出来ませんでした。
*_?_?_1_*.*

またDBにも同じ用にデータが入っており、どのようにwhere句で指定すると、対象に出来ますでしょうか。

初歩的な事で申し訳ないのですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

前提として、`ls`や`mv`などのファイル操作で指定できるのは正規表現ではなく**ワイルドカード**です。そして正規表現とワイルドカードでは同じ記号でもその意味が異なります。

`?`は正規表現だと「直前の文字の0,1回の繰り返し」ですが、ワイルドカードでは「**任意の一文字**」を表します。

質問の例に対してワイルドカードで(雑に)マッチさせるなら、以下の様な記述になります。

```
????????????_?_?_1_*
```

---

MySQLの`where`句でパターンマッチをする場合も正規表現ではなくワイルドカードの指定になりますが、扱う記号が微妙に異なるようです。私自身あまりMySQLは詳しくないので解説は省略させてもらいます。

参考： [MySQLの使い方 パターンマッチングで比較](https://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/select/index7.html)

Comment: cubickさん　ありがとうございます！うまくいきました。実はmvするまえにgrepでファイルが引っかかるか検証していたのですが、同一の記述でも引っかかりませんでした。同じosでもコマンドによって記述方法が違うんですね。。。